# Landscape RestAPI: GetPackages needs its query parameter; however, I want to return all packages

Tags: landscape, apic

Does the RestAPI allow for wild cards, as I have tried `*` and `%` as they are as well as their URL encoded versions when trying to get it to list all packages, by using tag, but none of those attempts work.

```
query=tag:*
query=tag:%
```

As : also has to be encoded

```
query=tag%3A%2A
query=tag%3A%25
```

As `GetPackages` needs its query, how can I force it to return all packages?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't appear to be Ubuntu related as it asks for programming help

Comment: Landscape is an Ubuntu product which is why I am posting my question in Ask Ubuntu.